# Change post contents after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am developing a simple web with laravel.
There is a post saying something about the product and there is a button at the end of the post which would open the form. Both post and the form are in different views partials so i want to include them.

I want to open the form in the place of where post was.

I was thinking if using blade file its possible to check @if button clicked and to include what i need.

Or i could try using javascript, is it possible to include different blade.php after a button click to change to contents?
Im pretty new with js by the way...

Comment: You can use bootstrap modal

Comment: You could try a number of things. Having a hidden textarea which mirrors the content of the page section and sends an ajax request to update the backend is one of many ways to solve this. However as it stands this question is too broad to be answerable. There's just too many unknowns to provide a reasonable answer. Once you've settled on a technology and have made an attempt at a solution but are stuck you can ask a new question.

Comment: I will try bootstrap modal as @DeepanshSachdeva suggested. Thanks for quick answers.